# postgresql why WHERE IS NULL clause not working

Tags: postgresql

Hello I am practicing PostgreSQL

I have this problem I have a dummy data and left some fields empty so I can try updating them but is not working

```
UPDATE parts
SET description = 'None Available'
WHERE description IS NULL;
```

// This is not working for whatever reason If I say WHERE description IS NOT NULL then it updates everything the not empty description and the empty description fields.
But when I say WHERE description IS NULL trying to only target and update the empty field descriptions it wont update.

Is there another way to do this clause? or where am I going wrong?

Here is the data:

SELECT * FROM parts LIMIT 10;

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id    |   description        |  code       |   manufacturer_id   |
|   0     |   2-color LED        |  V1-131     |         8           |
|   1     |   Passive Buzzer     |  V1-006     |         3           |
|   2     |   2-color LED        |  V1-011     |         8           |
|   3     |                      |  V1-031     |         4           |
|   4     |   Vibration switch   |  V1-002     |         7           |
|   5     |   Photo resistor     |  V1-018     |         5           |
|   6     |   Key switch         |  V1-004     |         3           |
|   7     |   Tilt switch        |  V1-020     |         7           |
|   8     |   Full-color LED SMD |  V1-009     |         8           |
|   9     |                      |  V1-005     |         6           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Probably there aren't any NULLs in `description`, but there are empty strings.

Comment: so how do call empty strings? with that WHERE Clause

Comment: `WHERE description = '' OR description IS NULL`   ( a trim() might indeed be needed...)

Comment: `WHERE description = ''`, or `WHERE trim(description) = ''`